# fastest tcp/ip stack

Tags: operating-system, tcp

What is the currently accepted OS with the fastest TCP/IP stack?  Im not interested in bandwidth but rather speed.

Ive seen NetBSD and Solaris as top dogs.

Regards

Comment: "speed" as in what exactly? Latency? Connection speed? Under heavy load? Unloaded?

Comment: latency under relatively no load

Answer (score 0, accepted):

6wind, wind river provide data path TCP stack, which are 10 more times faster then Linux original stack, as they stated.

Answer (score 0):

I once read a complete article regarding many different speed / scalability aspects between operating systems, and when it comes to networking both NetBSD **and** FreeBSD are top performers.

With low load as you mentioned in the comment, NetBSD will probably outperform FreeBSD. IIRC, FreeBSD's benchmarks returned consistent results under any load, whereas NetBSD started off quicker, and gradually got slower. This was the case for most of the tests.

I'll keep trying to find that article but a quick Google just now returned no results as of yet.

Comment: Didn't Microsoft "borrow" the NetBSD stack for Windows 7? I'm pretty sure they had good reasons to pick that particular one.